# My sass files are not being detected by my html files

Tags: html, sass, mobile-website

Idk what I'm doing wrong. But none of my scss is registering on the site. Should I use @use instead of @import because I have tried both to no avail.

Comment: <link href="app\scss\style.scss" type="text/scss" rel="stylesheet/scss" /> this is what I'm linking and it's not working.

Comment: You cannot link to a scss file in HTML. You need to compile your scss to CSS and then link that file in your HTML. You do this by typing sass --watch style.scss style.css in your terminal. 
 
Sass has a guide for how to get started!
https://sass-lang.com/guide